# wget SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, wget

I'm trying to pull a report down using the following:

https://user:password@domain.com/ReportServer?%2fFolder+1%2fReportName&rs:Format=CSV&rs:Command=Render

And it just pulls an html page and not the csv file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What does the HTML file say? Something like "acess denied"? And while you're at it, try

```
wget --user bob --password 123456 'https://domain.com/ReportServer?%2fFolder+1%2fReportName&rs:Format=CSV&rs:Command=Render'
```

Make sure you are using quotes. Otherwise, the shell will cut off the command before the first ampersand.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.
I also upgraded wget to the latest version 1.12.

I'm now doing the following:

wget --user bob --password 123456 --content-disposition 'https://domain.com/ReportServer?%2fFolder+1%2fReportName&rs:Format=CSV&rs:Command=Render'

And getting a 401 unauthorized error 3 times.
content-disposition was added to tell it to download the CSV file and not just an html page ...

Thoughts?

Comment: --content-disposition can only make it worse. Also, don't forget https:// at the beginning at the URL. It shouldn't, but sometimes does make a difference. 401 Unauthorized means your password is wrong. Are you absolutely sure that the password is correct? When you enter the URL in your browser, does the page show up after a username/password dialog?